# issue with my attempt at diffie-hellman key exchange

Tags: python, cryptography, python-cryptography

I've been trying to write some code in python to create a diffie-hellman key exchange, but I found that any value for "n" that is large enough to be secure seems to cause the code to freeze up when calculating the partial key. From what I understand a 2k bit value for n is commonplace. It seems that any number larger than 2^20 (a value that leads to a 21 bit key which can be brute forced) causes the code to stop working. I know there are some libraries that can be used, but I am using this as an exercise too write code that will work from scratch (aside from random). Thanks for any help you can provide. My code is below.

```
import random


#shared public numbers
g = 7817
n = int(2 ** 20)

def generate_partial_key():

    #let in the shared numbers
    global g
    global n
    #calculate private key
    a = random.randint(1,n)
    #find partial key
    b = (g ** a) % n    
    print('Your partial key is', b , 'send it to your partner. Your private key is', a, 'keep it somewhere secret.')


def find_shared_key():
    #let in the shared numbers
    global n

    #getting the information the user has
    partial_key = int(input("The partial key sent by your partner: "))
    private_key = int(input("Your private key: "))


    #calculate the shared key
    shared_key = (partial_key ** private_key) % n

    #give the user the info

    print("The key you share with your partner is ", shared_key, "keet it secret!")


def encrypt():

    global g

    #getting the key
    shared_key = int(input("Enter your shared key."))

    #turning the key back into a number

    #Get the messege
    message_text = input("What's your messege: ")

    #turning the messege into a list of numbers
    message_as_list = []
    
    for x in message_text:
        message_as_list.append(int(ord(x)))

    #obfuscating the numbers

    encrypted_list = [ (i * shared_key) for i in message_as_list]
    
    
    #give the user info

    print('your hidden messege is: ', encrypted_list)


    

def decrypt():

    #getting the key
    shared_key = int(input("Enter your shared key."))

    #Get the encrypted messege

    message_list_numbers = input('Enter the encrypted messege (omit brakets)').split(',')

    #turn the message into a numbers
    
    #use shared key to decrypt

    decrypted_list_numbers = [int(i / shared_key )  for i in message_list_numbers]

    #turn decripted messege back to ascii

    decrypted_list_letters = [chr(i) for i in decrypted_list_numbers]
    final_messege = ''.join(decrypted_list_letters)

    #give the user info

    print('Your decrypted messege: ', final_messege )



func = input("p: partial key. s: shared key. e: encrypt. d: decrypt.")

#decide what you are going to do with the program
if func == 'p':
    generate_partial_key()
elif func == 's':
    find_shared_key()
elif func == 'e':
    encrypt()
elif func == 'd':
    decrypt()
else:
    print("Invalid imput. Run program again.")
```

Comment: As to `b = (g ** a) % n`, `(partial_key ** private_key) % n`  and similar: **Don't** do modular exponentiation that way. Instead, use the three operand version of the [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function. So `b = pow(g, n, b)` and `pow(partial_key, private_key, n)` are the correct usages.

Comment: Already in my answer. I was typing, yes? :P

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are important to get right:

1. Use predefined domain parameters such as the ones defined in [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526.html#section-3). You cannot just use any value.
2. If you perform a modulus exponentiation then you should [use a predefined function](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526.html#section-3) for it.

First doing the exponentiation and then the modulus is a really bad idea, if just for the size expansion alone: remember that each multiplication **doubles** the size of the number, and the exponent for DH will be pretty large. "modpow" operations use shortcuts to calculate this efficiently (so do you if I'd ask you to calculate 5^200 (mod 10) ).

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for learning purposes, you should just replace every instance of `(g ** a) % n` with `pow(g,a,n)`, as Python's `pow` function has the ability to do modulo powering and it does it [efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Also, doing `x / i` doesn't work with modulo as 1/i is not the inverse of i in (mod n). It can be obtained by `pow(i,-1,n)` (the inverse only exists when i is coprime to n). So, `x / i` is done as `(x * pow(i,-1,n)) % n`.

If you need further material, I recently wrote a [post](https://medium.com/intuition/basics-of-mathematical-cryptography-408fdee23826) that features the implementation of what you're doing in Python (it's called ElGamal public-key cryptosystem).

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to create shared keys efficiently! I am still working on the encrypt/decrypt algorithm, but this was my big stumbling block.